# mod rewrite clean url for search box

Tags: search, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, clean-urls

I have mod rewrite enabled to remove all page extentions....

This is done in httpd.conf as I am using apache on windows

the setup I have is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

and this makes `domain.com/bookings.html`

appear as `domain.com/bookings`

I have php enabled in html files, so it parses all pages for php

But I have now put a search box on my site, and if I search for "music" it will use the url:

```
domain.com/search?q=music
```

I would like my urls to look like:

```
domain.com/search/music
```

But also, I would like to be able to type

```
domain.com/search/abba
```

And it would load the page "search.html" lets call it "search" and it would add the parameter ?q=abba , but then still look like the above example in the URL bar

I'm sure this can be achieved with mod rewrite but I am not sure how to phrase the expression.

Thanks in advance for any help I receive :)

Comment: Your acceptance is NULL. Improve on that else you will stop receiving help here.

Comment: how do i do that? im new to stack exchange, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the kind of URLs in your html: `domain.com/search/music`

add this in your `.htaccess` file in your DocumentRoot.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (search)/([\w\d]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html?q=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

or add this to your `.conf` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (search)/([\w\d]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1.html?q=%2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: that gives me error page, i tried in httpd.conf, and didnt work so tried in htaccess and didnt work :cry:

Comment: i have a generic error page for all errors, but apache logs says 302

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P This shouldn't be a 302 redirect as this is an internal redirect. Do you have any other rewriterules?

Comment: done everything you suggested and nothing has broken with the new line so im happy but it still wont re-write the url

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P where are the rule to remove `.html` located?

Comment: the very first bit of code i pasted in my question is the code to remove the .html extenstion

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P I mean, is it in your `.conf` file or a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P Remove that from there add it in `.htaccess` I order of how I will be posting it in the answer.

Comment: ok have done that and now getting error 400 bad request.... at least thats something

Answer (score 0):

You may just add one simple RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

So all in all:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Oh by the way:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: tried the code and it doesnt auto rewrite when i submit form, and it also loads error page when i type /search/music in url bar

Comment: are you sure you restart the server each time you make a modification of the vhost? is it a `vhost` or a `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes i always reboot apache server if i modify htaccess or httpd.conf.... im not sure if i need to for htaccess but i do anywaay